# Display image only on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Can somebody help me modify the below code to display image only in mobile view. Right now, it is always visible.

```
<style type="text/javascript">
      .icon-xyz
      {float: left; width: 22px;cursor: pointer;background: none;}

      @media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)
     {.icon-xyz {float: left;width: 22px;background: none;cursor: pointer;padding: 0 13px !important;}}

</style>
```

Following is the script to add image :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var loc = window.location;
      if (loc.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf('/home/') > -1)
      {
      $("#icon-xyz").css("background", "url(/images/Icon1.png) no-repeat");
      if($.cookie("lang") == "es")
      {
      $("#icon-xyz").css("background", "url(/images/Icon2.png) no-repeat");
      }
      }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ad8bc8tv/1/

Comment: What do you consider *mobile*?  Mobile devices are considered anything that can be carried or moved freely, which includes laptops, tablets (ipads), pdas, cellular phones, etc.  Some use the same dimensions and resolutions as what you may find in the typical desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` you won't be able to test this media query on your desktop browser, as it will only execute on *devices* that match those parameters.

That may be one reason it appears not to work.

For testing in a desktop environment try using `max-width` and `min-width` instead, as these relate to the size of the browser window not the screen size of the device.

In fact, Google, in their words, ***strongly discourages*** use of `*-device-width` media queries for reasons relating to legacy browser reporting and adaptability ([more details](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)).

In terms of a solution, here's one CSS method that may work for you:

```css
.icon-xyz {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) and 
   (orientation: portrait) { .icon-xyz { display: inline; } }
```

```html
<img class="icon-xyz" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxwo49q0/1/)