# Media query not working with max-width but working with max-device-width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adapt my site to tablets so when I include external CSS file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 960px) and (max-device-height: 1280px)" href="/css/tablets.css" />
```

the media queries work but when I use `max-width` and `max-height` they don't work. And the funny thing is that when I try to use media queries for landscape mode, it is the opposite situation:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (max-device-height: 960px)" href="/css/tablets.css" />
```

doesn't work whilst `max-width` and `max-height` do work. What's up with that?

For testing, I use iPad Mini Retina.

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36749882/3597276

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you didn't use **viewport** in head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I did test the code and it works fine.